# How do I test an Express.js app with AVA?

Tags: express, testing, ava

I can test my models fine with AVA, but I would like to also test the routes.

I feel it should be possible to access the Express app object, and pass it a URL, then see what comes back, but I do not know how to get the Express object to use it.

Comment: Please provide a route you want to test. Besides, which testing do you want, unit testing or integration testing?

Answer (score 3):

After some playing around and referencing the [supertest repo](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest), I was able to get the following working:

```js
const test = require("ava");
const request = require("supertest");
const express = require("express");

test("test express handler with supertest", async t => {
  // in async tests, it's useful to declare the number of
  // assertions this test contains
  t.plan(3);
  
  // define (or import) your express app here
  const app = express();
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
      message: "Hello, World!",
    });
  });
  
  // make a request with supertest
  const res = await request(app).get("/").send();
  
  // make assertions on the response
  t.is(res.ok, true);
  t.is(res.type, "application/json");
  t.like(res.body, {
    message: "Hello, World!",
  });
});
```

I tend to run AVA with the following shell command:

```sh
yarn ava --verbose --watch
```